# Modifying PostgreSQL Table for Handling Multiple Delivery Modes

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm working on a project where I need to modify the PostgreSQL table structure to handle multiple delivery modes for an ordering system.

I have a table named `seller` with columns like `id`, `user_id`, `store_name`, etc.

**Current State:**
I currently have a `delivery_mode` column, but I need to allow for scenarios where a station can support both `air freight`, `sea fright` or only one of those.

For example, 1st scenario: `seller1` sells clothes, the only delivery mode available for this store is `air freight`. So, when the customer orders, the only delivery mode available is `air freight`.

2nd scenario: `seller2` sells phones, the delivery mode available for this store are `air freight` and `sea freight`. So, when the customer orders, the customer may choose using a `select` with values of either  `air freight` and `sea freight`

**Objective:**
I want to modify the table structure to accommodate multiple delivery modes (`air freight` and `sea freight`) while adhering to the relational model.

**Options Considered:**
I've considered using an array or JSONB column for `delivery_mode`.

**Question:**
What is the best way to modify the table to handle multiple delivery modes in a relational database?

**SQL Schema**

```
create table
  public.seller (
    id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4 (),
    store_name text not null,
    address text not null,
    user_id uuid not null,
    delivery_mode text null,
    //rest of the fields
    constraint seller pkey primary key (id),
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
delivery_method TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (delivery_method IN ('Sea Freight', 'Air Freight')),
```

Great for a small number of possibilties. Otherwise use a lookup table. JSON is overkill for this!

In response to the comment by the OP *"where it supports both sea and air freight?"* - you could do this (not sure if this is what you want - could you expand - possibly with an example on dbfiddle?):

```
delivery_method TEXT NOT NULL 
  CHECK (delivery_method IN ('Sea Freight', 'Air Freight', 'Sea or Air Freight'))
```

Comment: How would this look like if I tried to add data on the table for `seller` where it supports both sea and air freight?

Comment: @Maine - not sure if I understand what you mean here - I've added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two boolean columns, one for each delivery mode. This method is efficient for storage and querying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility using ARRAY data type (using PostgreSQL 14). The possible values for `delivery_mode` are  `["air"]` `["sea"]`, or `["air", "sea"]`.

You can create a [DOMAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createdomain.html) to validate the `delivery_mode` values.

```
CREATE DOMAIN modes_arr AS VARCHAR[]
  CHECK(VALUE = '{"air"}' OR VALUE = '{"sea"}' OR VALUE = '{"air", "sea"}');
```

Table column using the `modes_arr` domain:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  delivery_mode modes_arr
);
```

Add some data:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (DEFAULT, '{"air"}'), (DEFAULT, '{"air", "sea"}');
```

Query data:

```
SELECT * FROM t;

  1 | {air}
  2 | {air,sea}
```

The domain `modes_arr` will make sure that inserting values like this will fail: `'{"air", "road"}'`, `'{}'`, etc.